# Getting cannot read property of undefined error need help getting values from what should be a json object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to get values from what I believe should be a JSON object however I am starting to think it isn't.

first here is my code:

This part actually makes a call to IBM Bluemix's weather service and returns what should be a json object.

```
var weatherData;

function getWeather(latitude, longitude, startDate, endDate) {
   // Prepare output in JSON format

      var callURL = "https://REMOVEDFORSECURITYREASONS@twcservice.mybluemix.net/api/weather/v1/geocode/"+latitude+"/"+longitude+"/almanac/daily.json?units=e&start="+startDate+"&end="+endDate

      request.get(callURL, {
        json: true
      },
      function (error, response, body) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            //var meta = body["metadata"];
            //var id = meta["transaction_id"];
            weatherData = body;
        }
      });
}
```

This part should parse some data coming in from an sql database and then parse the weather data merge it and output it as you can see in the code below however I can do that part if I can just get the weather data I need.

```
function publish(rows)
{       
       var timestamp = rows[i].timestamp;
        var motestack = rows[i].motestack;   
        var temperature = rows[i].temperature;
        var spcond = rows[i].spcond;
        var ph = rows[i].ph;   
        var depth = rows[i].depth;
        var power = rows[i].power;   
        var turbidity = rows[i].turbidity;
        var piezoresistance = rows[i].piezoresistance
        var mgl_odo_sat = rows[i].mgl_odo_sat
        var longitude = "-82.49357"
        var latitude = "34.5244887"
        var startDate = "0312"
        var endDate = "0312"

        getWeather(latitude,longitude,startDate,endDate);

        var almanac = weatherData;

        console.log(almanac);

        //deviceClient.publish("status","json",'{"d" : { "time" : \"'+timestamp+'\" , "mote" : \"'+motestack+'\" , "temp" : \"'+temperature+'\" , "spcond" : \"'+spcond+'\" , "ph" : \"'+ph+'\" , "depth" : \"'+depth+'\" , "turbidity" : \"'+turbidity+'\", "power" : \"'+power+'\" , "piezoresistance" : \"'+piezoresistance+'\" , "mgl_odo_sat" : \"'+mgl_odo_sat+'\", "latitude" : \"'+latitude+'\", "longitude" : \"'+longitude+'\" }}', 1);
        //console.log("status","json",'{"d" : { "time" : \"'+timestamp+'\" , "mote" : \"'+motestack+'\" , "temp" : \"'+temperature+'\" , "spcond" : \"'+spcond+'\" , "ph" : \"'+ph+'\" , "depth" : \"'+depth+'\" , "turbidity" : \"'+turbidity+'\", "power" : \"'+power+'\" , "piezoresistance" : \"'+piezoresistance+'\" , "mgl_odo_sat" : \"'+mgl_odo_sat+'\", "latitude" : \"'+latitude+'\", "longitude" : \"'+longitude+'\" }}', 1);
        i=i+1;
}
```

This is the output I am getting from the above code. I have tried various things to get the key:value pairs however I get errors like "Cannot read property 'some key' of undefined". If I do something like body.almanac_summaries I get the almanac_summaries data but it is wrapped in undefined{} like the data below.

```
Connection established
Device Connected
Data received from Db:

undefined
{ metadata: 
   { language: 'en-US',
     transaction_id: '1491701143744:483526643',
     version: '1',
     latitude: 34.52,
     longitude: -82.49,
     units: 'e',
     expire_time_gmt: 1491426760,
     status_code: 200 },
  almanac_summaries: 
   [ { class: 'almanac',
       station_id: '380165',
       station_name: 'ANDERSON',
       almanac_dt: '0312',
       interval: 'D',
       avg_hi: 64,
       avg_lo: 39,
       record_hi: 86,
       record_hi_yr: 1967,
       record_lo: 20,
       record_lo_yr: 1998,
       mean_temp: 52,
       avg_precip: 0.14,
       avg_snow: 0,
       record_period: 30 } ] }
```

Comment: `request.get()` is **asynchronous**. You can't eat a pizza before it gets delivered which is what you are trying to do by consuming data that hasn't been retrieved yet

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)